# Wait until video loads to capture snapshot as image

Tags: javascript, mp4, video-capture, jquery-deferred

I'm working on a script that will take an mp4 video and create a snapshot of the first frame. The purpose for doing this is some mobile browsers won't play a mp4 on load. It will show the mp4 with a play button. Therefore, creating a snapshot will be a good fallback for mobile devices.

**I have a basic snippet already, and it works 70% of the time.** However, when it doesn't work I think I'm having issues with the script trying to take a snapshot from a cached video, or it's trying to capture before the video fully loads. Does anyone has suggestions on how to make this 100%? I've tried deferring lines of code to wait until everything loads, yet sometimes it doesn't work.... What has helped a little is adding a small `setTimeOut`...

```
( function( window, $ ) {

const document = window.document;

const ImgSnapshot = (el) => {
    //setup variables
    const $el    = $(el);
    const video = $el.find(".wave-animation__container").get(0);

    $(video).ready( () => {

        setTimeout(() => {

            function createCanvas(){


                //create a canvas obj
                let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
                canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
                canvas.getContext('2d')
                    .drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                //wait until we have the canvas object captured
                return $.Deferred().resolve( canvas ).promise();
            }

            createCanvas().done( ( canvas ) => {
                   //create an image element to append
                   let img = document.createElement("img");
                   img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
                   img.classList.add('hide-for-medium', 'snapshot');

                   $el.append(img);

                   video.classList.add( 'show-for-medium' );
               });
           }, 150);



       });

   };


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.js-wave-animation').each(function(){
            new ImgSnapshot(this);
        });

    });

} )( window, jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a different approach for this problem. Instead of using `deferred` objects to check if video is loaded how about using `media events` of `video`

```
<video width="400" controls id="myvideo">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jqvideo = $("#myvideo");
    var video = jqvideo[0];
    video.addEventListener("loadeddata", function() { 
        console.log("loaded");
        let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        let img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
        $("body").append(img);
    }, true);
    jqvideo.find("source").attr("src", "yourvideourl.mp4");
</script>
```